# FragmentActivity cannot be converted to OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and wanted to set one of the `editText` in `fragment` clickable. However,I get error as below.

**Error**

```
 Error:(91, 47) error: incompatible types: FragmentActivity cannot be converted to OnClickListener
```

[image]

How to solve ?

Comment: do `timeIn1.setOnClickLisetener(this);`

Comment: `Error:(90, 36) error: incompatible types: myClass cannot be converted to OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using getActivity() method you just use this reference it will work

```
timeIn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: did you implement onClickListener inside fragment

Comment: In my case i create a fragment which implement the onClickListener interface which  override onclick method and i write above code inside oncreateView method and handle all process inside onclick method using switch case if you have any doubt then i can give you my code

Comment: Lol!! It does the trick.  I'm sorry for asking such a silly question...I forgot to implement `onClickListener`..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an `Activity` `Object` in a `View.OnClickListener` `Object`.

If you want to implement the listener and then as you might have used in the activity `timeIn1.setOnClickListener(this);` in `Fragment` you do this

```
timeIn1.setOnClickListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

it's either;

```
time1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

or;

```
time1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener({
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v) {

    }
});
```